# Vertically align text in a asp.net dropdown list control

Tags: html, asp.net, css, html-select

How do I vertically align a text in a asp.net dropdownlist control?
I researched the web and found several proposed solutions with padding etc. but none seem to work.
This is my code.

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown">
    <asp:ListItem>sds</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>ddd</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>xxx</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown
{
    height: 35px;
    background-color: Blue;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add line-height equal to the height:

```
.dropdown {
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    ...
}
```

Comment: did you remove the padding?

Comment: I tried both with padding and without and none work. 

    .dropdown
    {
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        background-color: Blue;
        font-size: 15px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .dropdown
    {
        height: 35px;
        line-height: 35px;
        background-color: Blue;
        font-size: 15px;    
     }

Comment: the issue is on IE (aligns to the bottom) and with Firefox (aligns to the top). On Chrome it Works fine.

Comment: Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yvZmC/ ; Must be some style being applied from elsewhere. Try creating a reset skin for the control.

Comment: This is quite interesting.
Acessing the link you sent it really works.
So I copied the exact same code of yours into an htm file into my Visual Studio.
When I ran it through Visual Studio "Play" button and it opens as http://localhost:3420/htmlStyles2.htm it still does not work!
On the other hand when I access the exact same file directly on the browser double clicking it (C:\Test\htmlStyles2.htm) it works!!!
So the problem seems to be with access through Visual Studio localhost. Any clue on why that might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: I found the issue! It's something with IE compatibility mode.
Discovered that on the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951127/odd-behaviour-in-web-page-when-page-uses-localhost-vs-machines-name?rq=1

The only thing I needed to do was to click on the compatibility mode button next to the url in IE and the alignment started working.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Padding will work .check out the following jsfiddle

```
<select class="dropdown">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

.dropdown
{

```
background-color: Blue;
font-size: 15px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
```

}

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QeG2a/2/)

Comment: for me it does not work. tried your example and continues aligned to the bottom, not to the middle/center.

Comment: seems css is ignoring padding instructions on dropdownlist/select elements. On the other hand it works well for texbox/input type="text".

Comment: note: padding is being ignored just on IE dropdownlist (height is just enough to fit the text). On Chrome and Firefox the original code that I posted works well.