# Problems loading some CSS styles with Internet Explorer accessing from computer name

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, iis-7, web

I am having a very weird problem only with Internet Explorer (I'm using the version 9.0.8)

I have a web server installed on the computer (windows 7) running under IIS 7. I have used CakePHP framework for the site.

When i access it from my IP address everything works well but on the other hand, when I access it from the computer name, some CSS styles are not applied as well as some JS scripts.

The files are loading correctly because most of the CSS styles are applied and all of them load from one same file. But some of them, don't ask me why, are not applied.

Here you can take a look at the Internet Explorer inspector loading the site from both URLs:
http://s9.postimage.org/vjhg6ytsd/problem.png
[image]

With Javascript, what happends is that some functions seem to interrupt the flow of the rest. If I delete this "conflictive" functions then it works well. (but it always works well loading it from localhost or with the IP directly...)

Comment: Looks like the CSS file is cached, try a force refresh (cntrl f5)

Comment: I have already done it. Seems it is not.

Comment: Prepare yourself, it's probably this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-not-rendering-css-properly-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive/4967594#4967594

Comment: Omg, it was that!! I added `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` and it worked!
Post your reply and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [IE not rendering CSS properly when the site is located at networkdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-not-rendering-css-properly-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive/4967594#4967594)

Add this:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```