# Use attribute selector in inline style

Tags: html, css

At work we use a CMS. I need to use attribute selectors but, so, do not have access to the head-section. I tried to solve the problem using inline styles. That's my (simplified) HTML:

```
<div>
    <style type="text/css" scoped>

        a[href*="test"] { background: #000000;}

    </style>

    <a href="www.test.de">Test</a>
    <a href="www.nothing.de">Nothing</a>

</div>
```

I expected the first link to get a black background - but nothing changed (tested with IE10). As shown in the example I also tried to use the "scoped" keyword to force it... That did not work either. When you substitute the attribute selector by

```
a { background: #000000;}
```

it works fine for all the hyperlinks. Am I right with the oppinion that I cannot use attribute selectors when working with inline styles? Or is there somebody out there who can show how the task can be accomplished?

Comment: As I wrote we use a CMS and I don't have access to the <head>-section.

Comment: Well, the OP is using a scoped stylesheet, which should *not* belong in the page head, but there's the other issue that scoped stylesheets aren't supported to begin with...

Comment: Another thing, "inline styles" refer to inline style *attributes* - selectors cannot appear in inline style attributes, but they can be used in CSS embedded using style elements just fine.

Comment: I looked at the question again and there does not appear to be a difference in the two CSS rules you've listed. Are you sure you didn't mistype one of them?

Comment: Works for me till IE8, Here: http://jsfiddle.net/6k2vP/show/

Comment: Does `a[href*="test"] { background: #000000 !important;}` make a difference? Maybe there is a stray [!important around](http://jsfiddle.net/TD872/)

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/AmnEM/2

Comment: I used your jsfiddle.net examples and removed everything around it and it still worked. The strange thing is, that I now have two files with exactly the same content. But one shows it correctly and the other doesn't. I also changed some content to be sure there is no caching problem. I am getting nervous...

Comment: @Jan Are you sure you are not missing something, may be a typo ? Type copy pasting the code and then changing according to your needs.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for your help. I cannot explain why, but if I launch the page from network share it looks different than when I launch it from my desktop. On my desktop it looks normal (as I expected). There must be some setting in IE that does this. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. What I tried to achieve should work. The problem is not the HTML or CSS... it is IE. Now, that I became aware of this behaviour I also searched for it. There have been similar problems before as I encountered when searching. For further explanation see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-not-rendering-css-properly-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive) for example.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should have been posted as a comment, or the question should have been edited or deleted.