# HTML/CSS transferring of folder

Tags: html, css, directory, transfer

I was working on a local page and everything was working fine until I copied the whole folder into a different location and the graphics went all glitchy. What could be the reason for this?

I would also like to mention that I didn't do anything with the files. I would also like to add that my css file is linked locally within the folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>SLNG Phase 3 A7JJ</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#253C4F;">
<ul style="position:relative;left:192px;top:-3px;" class="topnav">
  <li class="menu1" id="ftab"><a target="content" href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li class="menu2" id="stab"><a target="content" href="projinfo/projinfowin.html">Project Information</a></li>
  <li class="menu3" id="ttab"><a target="content" href="projref/projref.html">Project Reference Documents</a></li>
  <!--<li class="menu4" id="ftab"><a target="content" href="testing/testing.html">TEST</a></li>-->
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

```html
#ftab{
 background-color:#E0E0E0;
}

#stab{
 background-color:#C1D2E0;
}

#ttab{
 background-color:#D4ECFF;
}
```

and also

```html
ul.topnav, ul.topnav ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relatove;
 list-style:none;
 text-align:center;
}

li{
 padding:5px;
 float:left;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
    <!--background-color: #254A93;-->
    padding: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

li:hover, li:active {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.menu1{
 width:90px;
 position:relative;
 left:5px;
}

.menu2{
 width:240px;
 position:relative;
 left:13px;
}

.menu3{
 width:325px;
 position:relative;
 left:21px;
}

.menu4{
 width:150px;
 position:relative;
 left:23px;
}
```

Then again, everything was working fine until i transferred. :( i really can't explain it.

Comment: Please need more details - HTML or jsfiddle :)

Comment: just html and css involved here :)

Comment: can you please create a fiddle?

Comment: oh sorry hahaha i just searched what jsfiddle is..... and i'm in the office and it's not loading properly. probably because i'm using IE8.

Comment: You can also try http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: @AlexanderSabiona there is no CSS in your post.  Can you elaborate what "glitchy" means.

Comment: Thank you.  Right now, your links are showing up as different colored boxes with some padding and centered text.  How would you like them to appear?

Also, they are appearing to the right, and Home and Project References are on top of Project Reference Documents...  Is this the "funky" behavior you're referring to?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, added the css codes.

Comment: @DanOrlovsky on top? they should be lined up horizontally, i just tried it again right now. err i wish i could post pictures.

Comment: @AlexanderSabiona take the classes out of your list items, and change the "float: left;" to "display: inline-block;"

http://jsfiddle.net/9op4s29r/1/  is this along the lines of what you're looking for?

Comment: @DanOrlovsky, your help was greatly appreciated along with everyone else who answered. My issue's been solved already. Oh, and i can't access jsfiddle here :( company wants us to use IE8 hahaha.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone that answered :) it seems i have found the answer thanks to this:

Link: [IE not rendering CSS properly when the site is located at networkdrive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4966952/ie-not-rendering-css-properly-when-the-site-is-located-at-networkdrive)

I just added this to the html files:

```html
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

Apparently, when accessing html files from a network drive it forces IE to load at IE version 7, or that's what i read. This is quite disturbing for me :(

Thanks again though :)

Answer (score 0):

Update all your image paths to their new folder paths.

Old

```
<img src="old/images/image.jpg">
```

New

```
<img src="new/images/image.jpg">
```

Comment: Yeah but i linked them locally, and besides i wasn't actually having problems with the images. It's the formatting, regarding the css style i think.

Comment: In that case, what do you mean by "the graphics went all glitchy," because it sounded like you forgot to update image paths in your question.

Comment: like the buttons looked different after transferring :( no images involved. just pure css

Comment: Still hard to help without the CSS because we're not seeing how the buttons are supposed to be styled.