# Does css conditional targeting on localhost work?

Tags: css, conditional-statements

On my localhost xampp this doesn't seem to work in IE

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Why is this and how can i fix this?

ps: uploading to my server and the css conditional statement works OK

Comment: What happens when you try to load the style sheet directly in the browser? (_viz_: `http://localhost/ie.css`)

Comment: Might wanna give http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167657/will-targeting-ie8-with-conditional-comments-work a read.

Comment: What is "doesn't seem to work"? Are you sure that on your local drive, the css file is in the same relative location?

Comment: @steveax, ie browser wants to open it.
mrlister, i even made it absolute to make sure. What i do notice ie also display <!--[if lte IE]> as if it was just text. 
j08691 going to look into  localhost[*] is a special case, that does render in standards mode

Comment: @alex "wants to open it" meaning it didn't load the style sheet in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

That code should work fine locally. Are you sure your stylesheets are in the correct order? If you have your IE overides listed before your normal stylesheet, they overrides might not be applied.

Does it work properly in IE8 when you remove the conditional comment? It should.