# Conditional formatting tags not working in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, formatting, conditional-statements

I am currently working on a web development where I am now doing my formatting to please IE 8 or newer.  I have done this for previous browser versions, but not ie8.  My issue is that my conditional formatting tags are no longer working for this version of IE.  Has something changed?

page: http://domain/includes/file.php

css file: http://domain/css/cssIE8.css

the tag in my page is as follows:

```
    <!-- [if gte IE 7]>
    <p>Show this in IE</p>
    <link href="../css/profileIE8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

When I remove the conditional formatting tags, all the other browsers find the file just fine.  Any thoughts?

I even placed the `<p>` tag in there to see if it would display in the page, it doesn't.  My understanding is that this specific conditional formatting tag would apply to all Internet Explorer versions NEWER than v7

Comment: And before anyone asks/comments upon it, yes I did look at MANY SO posts with the same issue, couldn't find any resolution for this issue...

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167657/will-targeting-ie8-with-conditional-comments-work

Comment: Just an FYI, you state "My understanding is that this specific conditional formatting tag would apply to all Internet Explorer versions NEWER than v7" is not correct, it would be IE7 _and_ newer, as the `gte` means "greater than or equal to". If you don't want this to apply to IE7, then you should just use `gt`. Not sure why it would not work for IE8...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space between `<!-- [if..` should be removed. Hope it helps!

```
<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <p>Show this in IE</p>
    <link href="../css/profileIE8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <![endif]-->
```

More info can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537509(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: UNREAL!  I totally copy and pasted that from a 'tutorial site', and it looked good to me, I kept messing with it, but never thought of that.  GOOD EYES!!!  UPVOTE FOR YOU! :)

Comment: I didn't notice it at first either until I started looking through the link I posted...Those type of things as so easy to gloss over and not even realize it. Glad to help =)

Answer (score 0):

You state:

> When I remove the conditional formatting tags, all the other browsers
>   find the file just fine. Any thoughts?

Not sure how that is true, as your `href` is `../css/profileIE8.css`, but the file path you gave as your css is `http://domain/css/cssIE8.css` so the file names are ***different***. Unless you mistyped one here, your `href` does not match your file path, and thus it is not finding the css file.

Comment: It's a relative path, it's being called from a file in the http://domain/includes directory, it has to drop down one to the root, then move into the css directory.

Comment: @MaurerPower--I see you got the issue solved. My point was that the file *names* (not the path) were different in your posted code above. `profileIE8.css` is _not_ `cssIE8.css`, relative path or not.