# Twitter bootstrap 3 form-horizontal not working in ASP.NET w/IE8

Tags: asp.net, webforms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a web form in ASP.NET with the control labels to the left of the input controls, but in IE8 they are one above the other. I am using html5shiv and respond.js as recommended. This is my latest attempt.  Our corporate standard is IE8 (I know, I know, don't get me started).  Any ideas how to make this work?  Thanks.

```
<div class="container"> <!-- for bootstrap  -->
<div class="row">       <!-- for bootstrap  -->
    <div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtProfitShareYear" class="col-md-2 control-label">Profit Share Year</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtProfitShareYear" placeholder="rule year">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtCompanyID" class="col-md-2 control-label">Company ID</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtCompanyID" placeholder="rule year">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="txtMaxPayAmount" class="col-md-2 control-label">Max Pay Amount</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtMaxPayAmount" placeholder="deferral amount ratio">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="btnModalSave">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <!-- /.row -->
</div>  <!-- /.container -->
```

Here's my entire head section. If I remove the conditional CSS, it works.

```
<title>Medical Group 401k</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="Styles/Site.css" />
<link href="Styles/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="Scripts/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="Scripts/Respond.min.js"></script>      
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://decisionsupport/WebLibrary/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/Site.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">

</style>
```

@cvrebert:  yes, that one space caused IE8 to just ignore the conditional CSS.
Instead of this:

```
<!-- [if lt IE 9]>
```

Needs to be this:
    `<!--[if lt IE 9]>`

Comment: Presumably Respond.js isn't working correctly. Have you checked everything mentioned on http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs ?

Comment: Please see my <head> section above. If I remove the conditional CSS, <!-- [if lt IE 9]>, it works.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And yes, thanks for the link, my page should be good to go. Everything else bootstrap seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hi have you made sure the script call to respond.js is bellow your CSS (but still in the head section of the HTML this caught me out initially).

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440765/conditional-formatting-tags-not-working-in-ie8), an extra @%^&* space in the CSS conditional mucks it all up.  Are you kidding me?

To quote a great American, "DOH!"

Thanks to all who responded.

Comment: Ah, so `<!--[if lt IE 9]>` instead of `<!-- [if lt IE 9]>` ?